# Sorting many languages in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a database with multi-languages :

| Name |
| --- |
| 经典老歌经典老歌500首 |
| 经典老歌500首大全 |
| 粤语老歌 |
| 目前為止最好聽版本 |
| 好优美的老歌回忆回味chineseoldsongs |
| 國語90年代金曲 |
| 一人一首成名曲50首國語懷舊經典金曲 |
| 태연-들리나요 |
| 에일리-얼음꽃 |
| 벤-꿈처럼 |
| 백지영-잊지말아요 |
| 다비치-이사랑 |
| 거미-눈꽃 |
| 거미-구르미 그린 달빛 |
| You're My Everything |
| Say You, Say Me |
| Said I Loved You...But I Lied |
| Right Here Waiting (Single Edit) |
| Hello |
| Goodbye |
| Casablanca |
| Careless Whisper |

I want to sort languages order, i use collate:

1. English - Korean - Chinese :
   icu_load_collation('en-ko-zh', 'english');
   SELECT Name from Songs ORDER BY Name COLLATE english;
2. Chinese- English - Korean :
   icu_load_collation('zh-en-ko', 'chinese');
   SELECT Name from Songs ORDER BY Name COLLATE chinese;
3. Korean - Chinese - English :
   icu_load_collation('ko-zh-en', 'korean');
   SELECT Name from Songs ORDER BY Name COLLATE korean;

I run SQL but the languages order nothing change, I think my icu_load_collation() function is wrong.  What exactly for icu_load_collation() or give me an idea for sort multi-languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finish the research issue.

Only use the code of the language you want to sort to the top list, Example: icu_load_collation('en', 'english'); English letters will be in the top list. Chinese use'zh' and korea use 'ko'.

I have an issue with 'ja', the English letters always before the Japanese letters ([Which Japanese sorting / collation orders are supported by ICU / CLDR / UCA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874198/which-japanese-sorting-collation-orders-are-supported-by-icu-cldr-uca)).

The docs to use icu_load_collation:

- https://sites.google.com/site/icuprojectuserguide/locale
- http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/#u_Extension
- https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/latest/common/bcp47/collation.xml