Comparing Kangxi Radicals in SQL Server
I have an SQL Server database table containing Japanese Kanji and Radicals. Running a SELECT on this table for a Kanji returns a single row as I expect. However if I run the same Query for a Kangxi Radical character, the result is every Kangxi Radical character in the table.
This query returns a single row as I was expecting:
select *
from Kanji
where Character = N'炎'

This one returns over 200 results, all from the Kangxi Radicals Unicode block:
select *
from Kanji
where Character = N'⺉'

Can anyone explain what is happening?
I placed an example on sqlfiddle.com:
https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=d13b6f22-da4a-49fb-815e-a3d7aa9f9514
The database was created using EF Core, so the collations I've tried are whatever the default is, plus Japanese_Unicode_CI_AI_KS_WS. Both give the same results.

Please provide some sample data in an online tool like sqlfiddle.

What collation(s) are you using?

https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=d13b6f22-da4a-49fb-815e-a3d7aa9f9514

Try a different collation. e.g., https://dbfiddle.uk/JobhaxW6

maybe relevant https://stackoverflow.com/q/29874198/73226
